# Can Not Set Parent Class on Web Extraction

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am having problems setting the correct parent class to extract some data from AliExpress. I have tried several variations, some pull off one row of information, the best I can do is pull off 8 rows of data. Normally I just need to set a parent class, however for this I can not work out the parent class and it is a `Div Class` and `ul Class` a div with no name `Div` and then a `Li Class`

link: `https://www.aliexpress.com/af/phones.html?trafficChannel=af&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=phones&ltype=affiliate&SortType=default&g=y`

---

```
''counter
myCounter = myCounter + 1
Worksheets("Sheet20").Range("B6").Value = myCounter
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set html = objIE.document
Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("gallery product-card middle-place") ' parent CLASS
'FOR LOOP
For Each element In elements
    DoEvents

    ''' Element 1
    DoEvents
    If element.getElementsByClassName("item-title-wrap")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0) Is Nothing Then ' Get CLASS and Child Nod
        wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = "-" 'If Nothing then Hyphen in CELL
    Else
        htmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("item-title-wrap")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href 'Get CLASS and Child Nod
        wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = htmlText 'return value in column
    End If
    ''' Element 2
    DoEvents
    If element.getElementsByClassName("item-title-wrap")(0) Is Nothing Then ' Get CLASS and Child Nod
        wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B").Value = "-" 'If Nothing then Hyphen in CELL
    Else
        htmlText = element.getElementsByClassName("item-title-wrap")(0).innerText ' Get CLASS and Child Nod 'src
        wsSheet.Cells(sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B").Value = htmlText 'return value in column
    End If
    ''' Element 3
```

**Results,** I can only pull off about 8 rows of data

[image: Aliexpress]

**Q) Can someone please advise on how to set the Parent Class, Here?** *I would like to stick with my code as I am limited in VBA and I do understand my code*

```
  Set Html = objIE.document
           Set elements = Html.getElementsByClassName("gallery product-card middle-place") ' parent
```

[image: Html2]

As always thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the url and please, for the love of our sanity, use the snippet tool to insert html via [edit] rather than repeatedly posting images of html. Instructions on using snippet tool covered in https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. We can't actually see inside those closed divs marked in yellow.

Comment: I don't think you understand what DoEvents does. You don't need to repeatedly yield control within your program as is.

Comment: Sorry QHarr if will defo do it the next when i post. This is the link (https://www.aliexpress.com/af/phones.html?trafficChannel=af&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=phones&ltype=affiliate&SortType=default&g=y) I only need to know which is the parent class so I can set it in my code.

Comment: I will remove the DoEvents, thanks for having a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone please advise on how to set the Parent Class, Here?

No parent needed. Target elements all have the same class name so use list-item then loop that returned collection.

```
Set elements = Html.getElementsByClassName("list-item")
```

> I can only pull off about 8 rows of data

The page is lazy loading and you will need to page scroll to get more elements. If you search for existing answers on lazy loading/scrolling you should find a number of good existing examples. They rely on the same basic strategies of which there are not many applied in VBA e.g.

1. Keep scrolling window by given height and counting target elements. Stop when target element count hasn't increased for n scrolls.
2. Find an element at the bottom of the page and scroll that into the viewport.
   This is variable as to whether works. Depends on page set-up. Often used as height to scroll by in scenario 1 above.

etc.....

---

Alternatively, use the browser network tab to monitor web traffic, when scrolling, and see if you can find any additional requests in network tab and reproduce those xhrs to get the additional data.

Comment: I did try that, it did not work I only got about 8, possibly due to it being lazy loading. I will give it another shot

Comment: It is exactly because of that. To get more results you need to scroll.